# SqlServer database reflection and autogenerating NLog.xml

Tags: c#, beginner, xml, t-sql, t4

This is my first attempt at using T4 templates and I thought I generate the `NLog.xml` with it by getting the tables and the columns from the database to automatically create all targets.

---

## SqlServer reflection

To get the information about the log tables I use a couple of helper methods and classes that support the database reflection via the [`GetSchema`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934(v=vs.110).aspx) method. I then *translate* the resulting DataTables into custom classes that I can easier use inside the template.

The main two are:

```
public static class SqlConnectionExtensions
{
    public static List<TableInfo> GetTables(this SqlConnection conn, string database, string tableSchema)
    {
        using (var columns = conn.GetSchema(SchemaCollectionNames.Tables, new SchemaRestriction
        {
            Catalog = database,
            Owner = tableSchema
        }))
        {
            return columns.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TableInfo(x)).ToList();
        }
    }

    public static List<ColumnInfo> GetColumns(this SqlConnection conn, string tableSchema, string tableName)
    {
        using (var columns = conn.GetSchema(SchemaCollectionNames.Columns, new SchemaRestriction
        {
            Owner = tableSchema,
            Table = tableName
        }))
        {
            return columns.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new ColumnInfo(x)).ToList();
        }
    }
}

public class SqlServer
{
    public List<TableInfo> GetTables(string connectionString, string database, string tableSchema)
    {
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn.GetTables(database, tableSchema);
        }
    }

    public List<ColumnInfo> GetColumns(string connectionString, string tableSchema, string tableName)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn.GetColumns(tableSchema, tableName);
        }
    }
}
```

They are supported by another few classes that hold the schema information and a few constants:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class SchemaColumnNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public SchemaColumnNameAttribute(string name) => _name = name;
    public override string ToString() => _name;
}

public class TableInfo
{
    public TableInfo(DataRow row)
    {
        var properties = typeof(TableInfo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = row[property.GetCustomAttribute<SchemaColumnNameAttribute>().ToString()];
            property.SetValue(this, DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? null : value);
        }
    }

    [SchemaColumnName("table_catalog")]
    public string TableCatalog { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("table_schema")]
    public string TableSchema { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("table_name")]
    public string TableName { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("table_type")]
    public string TableType { get; set; }
}

public class ColumnInfo
{
    public ColumnInfo(DataRow row)
    {
        var properties = typeof(ColumnInfo).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = row[property.GetCustomAttribute<SchemaColumnNameAttribute>().ToString()];
            property.SetValue(this, DBNull.Value.Equals(value) ? null : value);
        }
    }

    [SchemaColumnName("column_name")]
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("ordinal_position")]
    public int OrdinalPosition { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("column_default")]
    public string ColumnDefault { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("is_nullable")]
    public string IsNullable { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("data_type")]
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("character_maximum_length")]
    public int CharacterMaximumLength { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("numeric_precision")]
    public byte NumericPrecision { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("numeric_precision_radix")]
    public short? NumericPrecisionRadix { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("numeric_scale")]
    public int? NumericScale { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("datetime_precision")]
    public short? DatetimePrecision { get; set; }

    [SchemaColumnName("character_set_name")]
    public string CharacterSetName { get; set; }
}

public static class SchemaCollectionNames
{
    public const string Columns = "Columns";
    public const string Tables = "Tables";
}

public class SchemaRestriction
{
    public string Catalog { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Table { get; set; }
    public string TableType { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator string[] (SchemaRestriction schemaRestriction)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            schemaRestriction.Catalog,
            schemaRestriction.Owner,
            schemaRestriction.Table,
            schemaRestriction.TableType,
        };
    }
}
```

---

## T4

The database reflection code is compiled into a separate assembly that I reference in the template.

Finally I use it to generate the actual config with a T4 template which is the first time I wrote something like this (and because of this I set the [beginner](/questions/tagged/beginner) tag).

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)\$(OutDir)\Reusable.Core.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Reusable" #>
<#@ output extension=".xml" #>
<#
    var connectionString = "...";
    var database = "TestDb";
    var schema = "dbo";
    var defaultColumns = new [] { "Id", "Timestamp", "Environment", "LogLevel", "Logger", "ThreadId", "Message", "Exception" };
    var indentWidth = 3;
    var idColumn = "Id";
    var defaultLog = "_MainLog";
    var tablePrefix = "Test_";
#>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog
  xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  internalLogFile="c:\temp\NLog.test.log"
  internalLogLevel="Error">

  <!-- *** Autogenerated (<#= DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() #> (UTC)) *** -->      

  <!-- sub-templates -->

  <variable name="environmentNotAvailable" value="N/A" />
  <variable name="environmentLayout" value="${whenEmpty:whenEmpty=${environmentNotAvailable}:inner=${event-context:item=Environment}}" />

  <variable name="callsiteLayout" value="${callsite:className=true:fileName=true:methodName:true}" />
  <variable name="exceptionLayout" value="${exception:format=tostring:separator= | :innerFormat=tostring,message:maxInnerExceptionLevel=7:innerExceptionSeparator= | }" />
  <variable name="stackTraceLayout" value="${stacktrace:format=raw:topFrames=7:separator= » }" />

  <!-- full templates -->

  <variable name="debuggerLayout" value="DEBUG » ${level:uppercase=true} | ${message}${onexception:${newline}${exceptionLayout}}" />

  <#
    var tables = new SqlServer().GetTables(connectionString, database, schema).Where(t => t.TableName.StartsWith(tablePrefix)).ToList();
  #>
  <targets>

    <target xsi:type="Debugger" name="debugger" layout="${debuggerLayout}" />

<#
foreach(var table in tables)
{
    var columns = new SqlServer().GetColumns(connectionString, schema, table.TableName);
#>  
        <target xsi:type="Database" name="<#=table.TableName#>" dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="<#=connectionString#>">
            <commandText>
                INSERT INTO [<#=schema#>].[<#=table.TableName#>] (
<#
foreach(var column in columns.Where(c => !c.ColumnName.Equals(idColumn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
{
    PushIndent(CreateIndent(indentWidth, 4));
    Write(column.x.ColumnName);
    WriteLine(column.i < columns.Count - 2 ? "," : string.Empty);
    PopIndent();
}
#>
                ) VALUES (
<#
foreach(var column in columns.Where(c => !c.ColumnName.Equals(idColumn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select((x, i) => new { x, i }))
{
    PushIndent(CreateIndent(indentWidth, 4));
    Write(column.x.IsNullable == "YES" ? "NULLIF(@" + column.x.ColumnName + ", '')" : "@" +  column.x.ColumnName);  
    WriteLine(column.i < columns.Count - 2 ? "," : string.Empty);
    PopIndent();
}
#>


            )
            </commandText>

            <!-- Default columns -->
            <parameter name="@Timestamp" layout="${longdate:universalTime=true}" />
            <parameter name="@Environment" layout="${environmentLayout}" />
            <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level:uppercase=true}" />
            <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <parameter name="@Message" layout="${Message}" />
            <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${onexception:${exceptionLayout}}" />

            <!-- Custom columns -->
<#

foreach(var column in columns.Where(c => !defaultColumns.Contains(c.ColumnName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
#>
            <parameter name="@<#=column.ColumnName#>" layout="${<# Write(column.DataType == "float" ? "invariant" : "event");#>-properties:item=<#=column.ColumnName#>}" />
<#
}
#>
        </target>
<#
    }
#>   

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!-- Log everything to debugger -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="debugger" enabled="true" final="false" />

<#
foreach(var table in tables.Where(t => !t.TableName.EndsWith(defaultLog)))
{
#>
    <logger name="<#=table.TableName#>" appendTo="<#=table.TableName#>" minlevel="Debug" enabled="true" final="true" />
<#
}
#>   

<#
var mainLog = tables.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TableName.EndsWith(defaultLog));
if (mainLog != null)
{
#>
    <!-- Use the MainLog if no other log matches -->
    <logger name="*" appendTo="<#=mainLog.TableName#>" minlevel="Debug" enabled="true" final="true" />
<#
}
#>

  </rules>
</nlog>

<#+
private string CreateIndent(int width, int depth)
{
    return new string(' ', width * depth);
}
#>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### T4 Review

---

[NLog.xsd](https://nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd?r=redirect) is available, so you could have saved yourself the trouble manually creating the xml, when you could have generated classes from the xsd (using T4 perhaps :p) instead. Then you could create the NLog.xml in memory using POCO's before serialising it using built-in xml serialisation.

---

With your current settings, your xml is generated nested below the T4.

> ```
> <#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
> // ..
> <#@ output extension=".xml" #>
> ```

But you might want to generate the xml in a different location. What you could is attaching the T4 to the host (VS IDE) and writing to a different path. The standard output file will only contain log entries.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
// ..
<#@ output extension=".log" #>

<# 
 // Get the Visual Studio API as a service:
 var dte = ((IServiceProvider)this.Host).GetCOMService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;

 // Get the location of the NLog.xml file:
 var nlogFile = this.Host.ResolvePath(@"Configuration\NLog.xml");
#>
```

Writing to another file than the standard output is facilitated using [TemplateFileManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/T4.TemplateFileManager/). A tutorial can be found [here](https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/blog/re-using-t4-template-for-multiple-model-diagrams.html).

```
<#@ include file="TemplateFileManagerV2.1.ttinclude" #>

<# 
    TemplateFileManager manager = TemplateFileManager.Create(this); 
    // create a new output file 
    manager.StartNewFile(nlogFile);
#>
```

---

One massive step forward is to use Runtime T4, rather than Design T4. This way you can build re-usable templates with markup and code-behind. [Tangible T4 Extensions for VS](https://t4-editor.tangible-engineering.com/T4-Editor-Visual-T4-Editing.html) is available as plugin for an IDE. I leave it up to you to find out how these work. I use Runtime T4 to generate classes all over my solution.sln. The power of these beasts is huge!

Comment: I'll try these _tricks_ with my next template... but maybe you have some ideas what else I could generate? :-P The tangible extensions seems worth buying, and even the price is ok. If JetBrains really implements their [own T4 engine in Rider](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-5245) this would be awsome.

Comment: Good candidates to template are unit tests (or skeletonts), entity builders, DTO and DAO objects from business entities, end user email templates, state machines from xml or uml.